# Задание C++. d=2*c;

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Мне задали создать переменную со значением 2*с. И дать ей имя d. Т.е `d=2*c`. И вывести эту переменную на экран. 
Я создал переменную `d=2*c`. Вывел на экран `cout << "d: " << d << endl;` И получил ошибку что переменная `c` не известна (не идентифицирована). Как мне выполнить задание? Как бы Вы выполнили его?
Может быть `c` это константа? Или нужно просить у пользователя ввод числа `c`?

Comment: "Может быть c это константа? Или нужно просить у пользователя ввод числа c?" - Узнайте это у того, кто дал вам задание

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что  задание следует цель проверять как вы можете задать переменным другое имя. Хотя тут не совсем ясно,  я бы ответил так:

```
template <class T>
void f(T& c)
{  
  T& d = c;
  d *= 2;
  cout << "d == " << d <<endl;
}
```

т.е. я делаю  переменную `c` аргументом функции, чтоб было не важно какое значение имеет, а ссылька уже умножает ее на `2`

Comment: Хороший ответ. Если это учебное задание - то этот ответ ещё надо уметь отстоять:)

Comment: @nick_n_a ,  Ну если будут возражения, я бы сказал:  сначала вы сами четко сформулируйте свой вопрос...